# Is there a way to find the height of a UITextView in a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextview

I resize to fit UITexViews embedded in UITableViewCells but I would like to make the height of the cell be dependent upon the height of the text. Is there a way to find the height of the textview?
My app is Universal and needs to handle vertical and horizontal iPad layouts.

Update

---

I'm not sure what code you would like to see but here are some excerpts:
This code calculates the row height but has no access to the cell contents

```
func calculateSwitchesHeight (viewName: String, text:String) -> CGFloat {

let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "View")
let viewPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "(viewName == %@)",viewName)
fetchRequest.predicate = viewPredicate

if text == "" {
    return 0.00
}
if text.rangeOfString("*") != nil{ //titles
    if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Pad
    {
        return 60 // iPad
    } else { // iPhone
        return 40 // iPhone
    }
}
let charCount: CGFloat = CGFloat(text.characters.count)
NSLog("charcount = > %f", charCount)
if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Pad
{
    switch charCount {
    case 0 ... 89: return 100
    default: return charCount + 10
    }

} else { // iPhone
    switch charCount {
    case 0 ... 69: return 70
    case 300 ... 350: return 240 // good for 343
    default: return charCount + 00
    }
 }

} // end calculateSwitchesHeight
```

Here is how I invoke it:

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        // calculate length of text and adjust the height of row for that
        return calculateSwitchesHeight(viewName, text:getSwitchInfo(viewName, switchOrder: indexPath.row, sectionNumber: indexPath.section).switchItemText)
    }
```

and I get the text using this function

```
func getSwitchInfo (viewName:String, switchOrder:Int, sectionNumber: Int) ->(switchItemText: String, switchType: String, switchItemSetting: Bool) {

let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Switch")
let viewPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "(viewName == %@)",viewName)
let rowPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "(switchOrder == %i)",switchOrder)
var switchItemText = ""
var switchType = ""
var switchItemSetting:Bool = false
var switchValue:NSNumber = 0

fetchRequest.predicate = NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates:[viewPredicate, rowPredicate])
// Execute the fetch request
do {
    let fetchResults = try managedObjectContext!.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as! [Switch]
    let appConfig = fetchResults[0]
    switchItemText  = appConfig.switchDescription!
    switchValue  = appConfig.switchValue!
    switchType  = appConfig.switchType!
    if switchValue == 1 {
        switchItemSetting = true
     }

} catch let error as NSError {
    // failure
    print("Fetch failed: \(error.localizedDescription)")
} // end fetch results
return (switchItemText, switchType, switchItemSetting)
}
```

Comment: How about `textView.frame.height`?

Comment: My problem was how to embed such a method into a cell  function but I'll see how I can do that. Thanks,

Comment: I am far from expert in this area but I cannot see how to calculate heightForRowAtIndexPath. The functions I use all reference String variables (from CoreData) and I do not know how to convert a String into a UITextView. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: Note that there is some crude code in the calculation of row height where I attempt to adjust the cell height based on character count in the text String. Clearly this isn't a desirable approach.

Comment: I modified the crude calculation to give a more accurate cell height based on the number of characters in the text ... it isn't perfect but better than what I had previously:  
            var returnSize: CGFloat = 100.0
            let charCount: CGFloat = CGFloat(text.characters.count)

            if charCount > 100 {
                returnSize = charCount - (0.10 * (charCount - 100)) // this is for portrait
                return returnSize
            }
            return returnSize